# Signing an assembly in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, certificate

I am trying to sign my assembly, but I am getting an error:

> Error Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store.

This is what I did to start:

- I right click on my project in Visual Studio
- Click on Properties
- Click on Signing
- Click Sign the Assembly checkbox
- Select New
- I give it a name and password

But then when I go to compile my build, I get the error.

I then went to the .pfx file in my project directory, double clicked it and imported it into the certificate store (and entered the same password as when I created the certificate).

But I keep getting the same error when trying to build my project. I ***do not*** have the "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" selected as I am not using that feature.

How can I fix this problem?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

Comment: did you follow all steps from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123.aspx ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found what was causing my problem. I had to delete the following from my Visual Studio project file (.csproj):

```
<ManifestCertificateThumbprint>...</ManifestCertificateThumbprint><b
<ManifestKeyFile>...</ManifestKeyFile><
<GenerateManifests>...</GenerateManifests><
<SignManifests>...</SignManifests>
```

This fixed the problem, and I was able to compile by application.

Comment: +1 this worked for me.  I am still unsure why that stuff (`manifestcertificatethumbprint`) was in my csproj, perhaps it is a relic from once when I tried to deploy my winforms app as a clickonce project.

Comment: Also described in *[ClickOnce Signing Bug](http://nittygrittycoding.blogspot.dk/2007/06/clickonce-signing-bug.html)*. (For Visual Studio 2005; I don't know if it also covers Visual Studio 2010)

Comment: And in *[ClickOnce deployments](http://www.mokhan.ca/tools/2010/10/05/click-once.html)* (2010-10-05). This Stack Overflow question is referenced there (but it describes a somewhat different scenario - uses certificates; it has extra information about certificates).

Comment: Updated link for the article referenced above: https://www.mokhan.ca/7a4dcfdceb5da1848869708b9e25a717113440c39a66a18116240d5ed883b853.html

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce it. I did all the same steps as you mentioned, saved the project file and compiled and all is OK.

You should maybe try to follow the article *[How to: Sign an Assembly (Visual Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41(v=vs.110).aspx)*, but your steps really worked for a newly created C# class library project.

Comment: If I make a new project, I can get it to work fine.  But when Signing my current project, I am getting the same error.